# How to test websocket with jest and enzyme?

Tags: unit-testing, websocket, socket.io, jestjs, enzyme

I am building an webapp and wish to unit test it. It also has Socket.io websocket backend (expressjs backend) and socket.io client on react app which is create-react-app application. 
Here is the test so far:

```
import React from 'react';

// 3rd party imports 
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import { SocketIO, Server } from 'mock-socket';

// custom imports
import App from '../App';
import Tasks from '../components/Tasks';

describe('App', () => {
  let wrapper, shallowWrapper;
  const mockServer = new Server('ws://localhost:8080');
  window.io = SocketIO;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    wrapper = mount(<App />);
    //start web socket config with mock-server
    mockServer.on('connection', socket => {
      socket.emit('task', 'test message from mock server');
    });
  // end web socket config
    shallowWrapper = shallow(<App />);
  });

  it("renders", () => {
    shallow(<App />);
  });

  test('renders right text', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    const linkElement = getByText(/BI4 Monitor/i);
    expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('has one unordered list', () =>{
    expect(wrapper.find("ul")).toHaveLength(0);
  });

  it("displays initial empty list", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("li")).toHaveLength(0);
  });

  it("has Tasks component", () => {
    console.log(shallowWrapper.debug())
    expect(shallowWrapper.contains(<Tasks/>)).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

I am using this mock library:
https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket

Here is App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// 3rd party imports
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import { useImmer } from 'use-immer';
import _ from "underscore";

// custom imports
import { SocketUtil } from './utils';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks';

const socket = SocketUtil.init();

function App() {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState([]);
  function handleData(payload) {
    // data = [...data, payload]
    setMsg(m => m.concat(payload));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     socket.on('task', payload => {
       console.log("taskkkk")
       handleData(payload);
     });
  });


  return (
    <Container>
      <Row className="row">
        <Col xs={12}>
          <h1>BI4 Monitor</h1>
          {/* <Tasks/> */}
          {_.map(msg, function(m) {
            return (
              <p>{m.key}</p>
            );
          })}
          <Tasks/>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I wish to print that `console.log("taskkkk")` or basically just unit testing to see more then one `<p>{m.key}</p>` getting rendered but is not happening. 
Also I have tried with `https://github.com/romgain/jest-websocket-mock` but no luck.
Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: 1) Does your application work as expected? But not the tests? Would it be right to say that your question is "why the mock doesn't work?" or the is more to it? It's unclear. 2) What is `SocketUtil.init()`? Show the code. 3) Where is the test "to see more then one `<p>{m.key}</p>` getting rendered" ? 4) `it('has one unordered list ... .toHaveLength(0)` are you sure about `length = 0`, the name suggests 1? 5) Remove irrelevant comments and tests from the question. E.g `{/* <Tasks/> */}` ... Or maybe it should be `<Tasks>...</Tasks>`, in that case - fix it.

Comment: 6) Code for the `<Task>` is probably needed. 7) Github with a **minimal reproducible example** - is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to mock the WebSocket JS API by myself. Please refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68579278/4124267